# Creating User Defined Function in Spark-SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am new to spark and spark sql and i was trying to query some data using spark SQL.

I need to fetch the month from a date which is given as a string.

I think it is not possible to query month directly from sparkqsl so i was thinking of writing a user defined function in scala.

Is it possible to write udf in sparkSQL and if possible can anybody suggest the best method of writing an udf.

Comment: They say on the [official site](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) that Spark SQL is still an alpha thing, which [apparently has no official syntax reference](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Supported-SQL-syntax-in-Spark-SQL-td9538.html) at the moment. People who do know something about Spark SQL *might* hang around here, but at this point you might have better chance learning new things about it following the [Apache Spark mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/).

Answer (score 11):

You can do this, at least for filtering, if you're willing to use a language-integrated query.

For a data file dates.txt containing:

```
one,2014-06-01
two,2014-07-01
three,2014-08-01
four,2014-08-15
five,2014-09-15
```

You can pack as much Scala date magic in your UDF as you want but I'll keep it simple:

```scala
def myDateFilter(date: String) = date contains "-08-"
```

Set it all up as follows -- a lot of this is from the [Programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide).

```scala
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._

// case class for your records
case class Entry(name: String, when: String)

// read and parse the data
val entries = sc.textFile("dates.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(e => Entry(e(0),e(1)))
```

You can use the UDF as part of your WHERE clause:

```
val augustEntries = entries.where('when)(myDateFilter).select('name, 'when)
```

and see the results:

```
augustEntries.map(r => r(0)).collect().foreach(println)
```

Notice the version of the `where` method I've used, declared as follows in the doc:

```scala
def where[T1](arg1: Symbol)(udf: (T1) ⇒ Boolean): SchemaRDD
```

So, the UDF can only take one argument, but you can compose several `.where()` calls to filter on multiple columns.

**Edit for Spark 1.2.0 (and really 1.1.0 too)**

While it's not really documented, Spark now supports registering a UDF so it can be queried from SQL.

The above UDF could be registered using:

```scala
sqlContext.registerFunction("myDateFilter", myDateFilter)
```

and if the table was registered

```scala
sqlContext.registerRDDAsTable(entries, "entries")
```

it could be queried using

```scala
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE myDateFilter(when)")
```

For more details see [this example](https://github.com/spirom/LearningSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/sql/UDF.scala).

Comment: what about the `UDAF` (user-define aggregation function) ?

Comment: I've been wondering about that too, but haven't found any evidence that it's supported so far. It **is** supported if you're willing to write a Hive query, as you can see in [the tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/execution/HiveUdfSuite.scala)

Comment: It turns out this is being tracked in [SPARK-3947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3947) -- not yet supported.

Comment: For Spark 1.3+ use sqlContext.udf.register("myDateFilter", myDateFilter)

Answer (score 3):

In Spark 2.0, you can do this:

```
// define the UDF
def convert2Years(date: String) = date.substring(7, 11)
// register to session
sparkSession.udf.register("convert2Years", convert2Years(_: String))
val moviesDf = getMoviesDf // create dataframe usual way
moviesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("movies") // 'movies' is used in sql below
val years = sparkSession.sql("select convert2Years(releaseDate) from movies")
```

Answer (score 1):

In **PySpark 1.5** and above, we can easily achieve this with builtin function.

Following is an example:

```
raw_data = 
[

("2016-02-27 23:59:59", "Gold", 97450.56),

("2016-02-28 23:00:00", "Silver", 7894.23),

("2016-02-29 22:59:58", "Titanium", 234589.66)]


Time_Material_revenue_df  = 
sqlContext.createDataFrame(raw_data, ["Sold_time", "Material", "Revenue"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import  *

Day_Material_reveneu_df = Time_Material_revenue_df.select(to_date("Sold_time").alias("Sold_day"), "Material", "Revenue")
```