# What are Spark UDFS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been writing some transformers and estimators and I keep noticing udfs. I've read through the source and have a general sense of what they are for but I was hoping someone could give me a high level explanation.

What I have gleaned from the code is that you can create a udf and apply it such that it runs over each row in the dataframe for a particular column. I guess I am curious why we do it this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating User Defined Function in Spark-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031129/creating-user-defined-function-in-spark-sql)

Comment: Yeah I looked at that one, didn't feel like it gave the high level I am looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: UDF are just a way of extending the functionality of the framework while  using the SQL approach. Say you have some formulae you want to apply to some geo-tagged events, e.g. haversine distance. UDF let you define some `haversine` function, use it directly in your SQL query like in `SELECT haversine(x, y) from event ... `. Without that the alternative would be to convert back to RDD or other similar multi-step approach. UDF just make the functionality easier to express and read, behind the scene it's still just a `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the custom manipulation you write over your RDDs and DataFrames are essentially "user defined functions". You would register a UDF though so that you'd be able to use it in select statements used in Spark-SQL (sqlContext.sql("select myUDF(fieldname) from myRegistredDF")...

Answer (score 0):

UDF (User defined functions) and UDAF (User defined aggregate functions) allow to extend the language constructs to do adhoc processing on distributed dataset.
You can refer to this blog for detailed explanation.
https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/spark-custom-udf-example/