# Java Spark withColumn - custom function

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Problem, please give any solutions in Java(not scala or python)

I have a DataFrame with the following data

```
colA, colB
23,44
24,64
```

What i want is a dataframe like this

```
colA, colB, colC
23,44, result of myFunction(23,24)
24,64, result of myFunction(23,24)
```

Basically i would like to add a column to the dataframe in java, where the value of the new column is found by putting the values of colA and colB through a complex function which returns a string.

Here is what i've tried, but the parameter to complexFunction only seems to be the name 'colA', rather than the value in colA.

```
myDataFrame.withColumn("ststs", (complexFunction(myDataFrame.col("colA")))).show();
```

Comment: That is exactly what user-defined functions (UDFs) are for in Spark: see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031129/creating-user-defined-function-in-spark-sql

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should use a User Defined Function.
Let's suppose that you have a myFunction method which does the complex processing :

```
val myFunction : (Int, Int) => String = (colA, colB) => {...}
```

Then All you need to do is to transform your function into a udf and apply it on the columns A and B :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col}

val myFunctionUdf = udf(myFunction)
myDataFrame.withColumn("colC", myFunctionUdf(col("colA"), col("colB")))
```

I hope it helps

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in java - it doesn't let me take on more than one variable

Comment: This appears to be written in Scala, not Java as specified in the question.